# problem on the .exe created by the pyinstaler

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaler to create a .exe but it doesn't open, just create a cmd window for some miliseconds and close, fortunaly I could take a foto of the cmd at the right time and this was written:

```
traaceback (most recent last call last):
File "TEST.py", line 1, in <module> 
File "c: \ users \*****\ appdata \ local \ programs \ python \ python38-32 \ lib \ site-packages \ 
PyInstaller  \ loader \ pyimode3_importers py ", line 493, in exec_module 
   exec (bytecode, module.dict) 
File" pynput_init_.py ", line 40, in <module> 
File" c: \ users \*****\ appdata \ local \ programs \ python  \ python38-32 \ lib \ site-packages \ 
PyInstaller \ loader \ pyimod03_importers py ", line 493, in exec_module
exec (bytecode, module.dict) File" pynput \ keyboard \ _ init-py ", line 31, in <module  
File "pynputLutil \ _init_.py", line 76, in the ImportError backend
[40412] Failed to run the TEST script
```

I don't know what this means and how to solve the problem, I tried first on the auto-py-to-exe, and it gave this result, so I tried manualy by the cmd with  `pyinstaller TEST` but it's the same result on both.
If someone can help me I thank